# connecting remotely to a mysql server - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, windows

I have the following class, which I use to establish a `php` MySQL connection (the `$ipaddress` is totally valid, and used just to hide the actual ip address)

```
class DbConn {

    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $database;
    private $link;
    private $db;

    public function __construct($ipaddress) {
        $this->host = $ipaddress;
        $this->user = 'myuser';
        $this->password = 'mypwd';
        $this->database = 'mydb';
        try {
            $this->link = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password);
            if (!$this->link) {
                throw new Exception('Database connection error');
            }
            $this->db = mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->link);
            if (!$this->db) {
                throw new Exception('Cant use database: '. mysql_error());
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print_r($e);
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it on the `$ipaddress` host machine (localhost) it works perfectly ... now I'm trying to run it on a remote machine, so I can remotely connect to the MySQL server. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected par
y did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection fa
led because connected host has failed to respond.
 in C:\performance\browser_perf\DbConn.php on line 18
```

The currently machine I'm trying to connect from is a `Windows 8 X86` machine, and the MySQL server ins installed in a `Windows 7 X64_86` machine.  I have the following questions:

- do I have to have MySQL installed in the remote server (`Win 8`) as well, or the `php` interface could handle that connection for me?
- How do I assert the ip address is correct? I looked at it using `ipconfig`

Comment: It might be a firewall issue.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a client, which interacts with the server, you don't need a a MySQL server in the "client" machine. Check if the port 3306 is responding. a single **telnet IPofWin7MySQLServer  3306** should be enought

Answer (score 0):

You need MYSQL Server running **only** on the target machine (Win7)

Comment: @philippe Didn't you ask "do I have to have MySQL installed in the remote server"?

Answer (score 0):

In my.cnf on the MySQL server check if the bind-address setting is set to 127.0.0.1. If it is change it to 0.0.0.0.